# Loading data into a CSV file from Oracle Database using Spring Batch, boot and Spring Jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

Hi  i am using spring batch for the first time. My use case is that i have to load data from oracle db to a csv file using Spring boot and Spring Data. 
I am having difficulties configuring oracle db in ItemReader. Can someone help me out.

Here is my Code

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public PersonAcctRepository personAcctRepository;



    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<CustomerInsr> writer(){

        FlatFileItemWriter<CustomerInsr> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<CustomerInsr>();

        String exportFileHeader = "FIRST_NAM, MIDDLE_NAM, LAST_NAM";
        StringHeaderWriter headerWriter =  new StringHeaderWriter(exportFileHeader);
        writer.setHeaderCallback(headerWriter);
        writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"));

        LineAggregator<CustomerInsr> lineAgg = createCustomerInsrAgg();
        writer.setLineAggregator(lineAgg);



        return writer;

    }

    @Bean
    public LineAggregator<CustomerInsr> createCustomerInsrAgg(){

        DelimitedLineAggregator<CaresCustomerInsr> deliAgg = new DelimitedLineAggregator<CustomerInsr>();
        deliAgg.setDelimiter(",");

        FieldExtractor<CustomerInsr> fieldExtractor = createCustomerInsrExtractor();
        deliAgg.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
        return deliAgg;

    }

    @Bean
    public FieldExtractor<CustomerInsr> createCustomerInsrExtractor(){

        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<CustomerInsr> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<CustomerInsr>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String []{"firstName", "middleName", "lastName"});
        return fieldExtractor;  
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<CustomerInsr> reader(){

        RepositoryItemReader<CustomerInsr> reader  = new RepositoryItemReader<CustomerInsr> ();
        reader.setRepository(personAcctRepository);
        reader.setMethodName("findAll");
        return reader;  
    }


    @Bean
    public Job job(){

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
               .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
               .flow(step())
               .end()
               .build();

    }


    @Bean
    public Step  step(){

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
               .<CustomerInsr, CustomerInsr> chunk(10)
               .reader(reader())
               .writer(writer())
               .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, whats missing/wrong. stack-trace?

Comment: I am trying to read data from  oracle db, i am using Spring data repositories(JPA repository, using the findAll() method ). I  am giving the database properties in application.properties file. How should i configure the method(findAll()) and the datasource in the ItemReader

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is one I encounter frequently. So frequently that I wrote a small application (spring boot, spring batch) to provide for an opiniated implementation of your use case.

You can clone [the repo](https://github.com/mierasmade/jdbc-unload) and add your oracle driver manually. After adding the correct driver you can repackage the application to a new jar (if you use maven use the package build phase).

Provide your database credentials and the settings for unloading your data in the application.yml (this is an external configuration file, similar to the database.properties).

I took the liberty of providing you with an example that uses CustomerInsr as table and firstName, middleName and lastName as the columns you wish to unload:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@yoururl:yourport:yoursid
    username: 
    password:         

output-dir: your/directory/target/
commit-interval: 10
page-size: 10
delimiter: ","
quote: "\""
quote-escape: "\\"
table-definitions:
  - file-name: CustomerInsr.csv    
    select-query: "SELECT firstName, middleName, lastName"
    from-query: "FROM CustomerInsr"
    sort-column: firstName
```

Run the jar from command line with something like:

```
java -jar jdbc-unload-1.0.0.jar --spring.config.location=c:\yourlocation\application.yml
```

If you have any questions please feel free to ask me.